# Android 4.4 backspace not modifiying default text in a Kivy TextInput

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

Before upgrading my nexus 4 from Android 4.3 to 4.4(Kitkat) i could erase whith the BackSpace button a default text that i was casting on load in a TextInput. Strangely, now i cannot delete the text of this TextInput while using the default keyboard (the Google keyboard), but works perfectly with other keyboards that are available on Google Play. I don't know if it is an OS issue or my code needs modification or an upgrade to Kivy might be required.

my code looks as follows (in kv):

```
TextInput:
    id:txt_from_mail
    font_size: root.height * .044
    size_hint: (None,None)
    size: root.width*.65,root.height*.0833
    background_color:(1,2,0.7,0.9)
    foreground_color: (.2,.4,.5,.9)
    padding_y:self.height*.12
    text:"YourGmail@gmail.com" # this is the text that i cannot delete or modify
    multiline:False
    on_focus:root.clear_mail_feedback()
```

and in Python the function looks like that:

```
def clear_mail_feedback(self):
    self.the_mail_feedback.text="" # this is a label in my form that gives text feedback to users
```

EDIT : i can also add other findings. typing text in the TextInput, put the application in the background, call back the application, and try to edit your text, you cannot! could it be an issue with latinIME? with native coding??? clueless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with kitkat, kivy. There is a temp hack/fix [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/178)

Comment: I saw the link that you have provided but cannot find where the solution is or I might not have understood what should be done.can you please help explaining it.

Comment: The link is to a Pull Request that contains a temporary solution, to test it out you need to clone the py4a repo and checkout the `kitkat_keyboard` branch and build your distribution using this branch.

Comment: Sorry @qua-non to ask again, does it mean that I should do $./distribute.sh "kitkat_keyboard kivy"

Comment: Or should I use it in the build.py script?

Comment: This has been merged in master so one simply needs to make sure they have the latest py4a